# Picklist values showing on Lightning but not showing on Classic

Tags: lightning, picklist, dependent-picklist, classic

I have a picklist with 4 values. In **Lightning** all the values are displayed and the user can select them, but when the same user **change to classic** and try to edit the picklist just one of the values is displayed.

[image: Picklist values Classic vs Lightning]

Comment: Is there any recordtype on the object.

Comment: Yes, there are 4 recordTypes for the object (Contract). I checked and all the values of the picklist are available and associated with the recordTypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

[image: Knowledge Article]

The status category indicates the available values displayed on the picklist. In **SF Lightning** you can select values from other categories, but in **SF Classic** you **only** can select the values of the same category.

[SF Article about Contract Status Standard picklist](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321523&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1)